# SWT - TreeViewer - Single Select vs Multi-Select

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

*Please note Eclipse RCP is used.*

I have enabled Multi-select using CTRL+Mouse Click for an existing Tree Viewer. Now I need to provide two menus for Right Click:

```
 One menu item on Single Selection.
 A different menu item for Multiple Selection.
```

Currently extension definition through `plugin.xml` is available for Single Selection where the selected object is checked if it is an `instanceof` some value.

How to identify multiple select? What needs to be checked for multi-select in extension definition.

```xml
   <definition
        id="com.sample.rightclickmenu.singleselect.id.expression">
     <with
           variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">
        <iterate
              ifEmpty="false"
              operator="and">
           <or>
              <instanceof
                    value="com.sample.ExampleNGroup"> -> Where N=1,2,.. 
              </instanceof>
           </or>
        </iterate>
     </with>
  </definition>
```

When I multi-select between different N, what should be the extension definition.

```xml
   <definition
        id="com.sample.rightclickmenu.multiselect.id.expression">
     <with
           variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">
        <iterate
              ifEmpty="false"
              operator="and">
           <or>
              <instanceof
                    value=??>  -> what needs to be the value here.
              </instanceof>
           </or>
        </iterate>
     </with>
  </definition>
```

I hope I have explained the problem properly.

Comment: You are iterating through each item in the selection so the instanceof test is likely to be the same - you are just testing a single item in the selection at that point.  Since you have specified `operator="and"` the expression will check all the items in the selection match the instanceof - is that what you want?

Comment: I had given a sample definition for clarification. All I need is to differentiate a single select vs a multi-select. Value cannot depend on the type of Group as the combination of different groups possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `count` element to test the selection size

Single item selected:

```xml
 <with variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">
    <count value="1" />
    <iterate ifEmpty="false">
          ....
    </iterate>
 </with>
```

Two or more items selected

```xml
 <with variable="org.eclipse.ui.selection">
    <count value="(2-" />
    <iterate ifEmpty="false">
          ....
    </iterate>
 </with>
```

Comment: It worked with <count value="(1-" />. How do I get the options of Single select menu to not appear in multi-select? I want to make them both mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have too many combinations for single select that adding <count value="1" /> to every one of the combinations a difficult task. Any other way to do it easily?